# Angular-Web api post method of model is null

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, angular6

On below code always get model is null,But not issue for [frombody]string parameter 
Set cors in WebApiConfig

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins:"*",methods: "*", headers: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

//controller

```
[Route("SaveorUpdateCategory")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveorUpdateCategory(ModelCategory model)
    {
        string res = objcate.SaveorUpdateCategory(model);
        return Ok(res);

    }
```

//angular service

```
  SaveorUpdateCategory( model: any): Observable<any> {
     this.headers= new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
   let body = JSON.stringify(model);
   return this._http.post(this.BaseURL+"Category/SaveorUpdateCategory", model, this.options)
       .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

model sample is {categry:'Test',Id:'1'}
when passing single variable is getting value.but model always get null

installed cors as Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Comment: Can you post the c# code for ModelCategory

Comment: public class ModelCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("CategId")]
        public long CategId { get; set; }
        [Column("Category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [Column("IsActive")]
        public byte IsActive { get; set; }
       }

Comment: The model is case sensitive and i think you need to set all the properties of the model in angular (some properties can be null or default) and try again. Set the Json to {Category: 'Test', Id: 1, IsActive: 0} . Are you using the Byte for anything in Angular? if not then you probably need a seperate viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

Change your web api method as follows using FromBody ,

```
public void Disconnect([FromBody] ModelCategory model) {  }
```